# How do I pass variables between methods in java?

Tags: java, variables, methods

In the main method of my program I have a bunch of scanner input which I have passed into various methods using parameters. 
In those various methods I have done calculations, creating new variables. 
In my final method I need to add those new variables together, but the compiler will not recognize the new variables because they only exist in those other methods. How would I go about passing the new variables to my final method?

Comment: Do your methods return something other than `void`? If not, changing that might be a good first step.

Comment: I advice you to go through basic tutorial.

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: create a class variable it will help you

Comment: you cant learn programming from the ground by asking questions on SO, I advice you to look at same examples of the language you are learning , look at this http://www2.cs.uic.edu/~sloan/CLASSES/java/

Answer (score 4):

Instead of creating local variables create class variables.The scope of class variables is that they are global meaning you can access those variables anywhere in the class

Answer (score 4):

Variables created in methods are local to methods and [scope](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.3) is restricted to methods only.

So go for [`instance members`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html), which you can share among methods.

If you declare so, you don't need to pass them among methods, but you can access and update those members in methods.

Consider,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String i = "A";
    anotherMethod();
}
```

You get a compiler error in the below method if you try to access `i`, because `i`  is a local variable of the main method. You cannot access in other methods.

```
public static void anotherMethod() {
    System.out.println("    " + i);
}
```

What you can do is, pass that variable to where you want.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String i = "A";
    anotherMethod(i);
}

public static void anotherMethod(String param){
    System.out.println("    " + param);
}
```

Comment: What if you want to pass variables into the main method from somewhere outside of the code?

Comment: @bluemunch If you are running from command line, there. If it is in eclipse, you can do that in run configurations

Comment: Cool. Strangely enough, my implementation doesn't even make use of a main method, as parameters are passed into a Map from a different program altogether.

Comment: @bluemunch Hence you can use them directly right ? If it a web applicaion, yes. You many not need a main and it hits your servlet/whatever

Answer (score 1):

You can create a [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) and pass it to each method as parameter. At the end all you need is to iterate through the list and handle the results.

Answer (score 0):

Create an object with new variables and the method returning their sum.
In your methods use this object for new variables calculation.
Then use the object method for getting sum of new variables

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
public void doStuff()
{
    //Put the calculated result from the function in this variable
    Integer calculatedStuff = calculateStuff();
    //Do stuff...
}

public Integer calculateStuff()
{
    //Define a variable to return
    Integer result;

    //Do calculate stuff...
    result = (4+4) / 2;

    //Return the result to the caller
    return result;
}
```

You also could do this(You can then retrieve the variable calculatedStuff in any function in the class):

```
public class blabla {

    private Integer calculatedStuff;

    public void calculateStuff()
    {
        //Define a variable to return
        Integer result;

        //Do calculate stuff...
        result = (4+4) / 2;

        //Return the result to the caller
        this.calculatedStuff = result;
    }

}
```

But as everyone else suggest, I also higly recommend to do a basic Java tutorial.