# Make a Scanner object declared in main() accessible in all methods

Tags: java, scope

I tried to declare a new Scanner object.

It works fine in the main() method, but in the other methods it is not accessible.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Exe1GenericSort {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);

        start();

        int i = input.nextInt();
    }

    public static void start() {
        int i = input.nextInt();
        //...
    }
}
```

I tried to write the `Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);` above the main() method but it still won't work...

Comment: Do you understand scoping? If you create a Scanner in main, it can only be used in main unless you pass it as a argument to another method.

Comment: yea.. i know..
i was programming in c for a long time and now back to java
but i remember there was a way to declare a scanner somehow so outside of the main it still can recognize it,
(tried to declare public Scanner input = new.....)
still no good...

Comment: The ```input``` variable has been declared inside the main method, and therefore will only be available inside the main method's scope.

Comment: If two people were talking in a room, would you expect to know what was said if you were in another room?

Comment: @RoiZrihan Afaik, variable scoping is the same in C as it is in Java.

Comment: i know scoping.. i just want to know how i make the methods recognize the scanner too.
there is a way, i used this 2 years ago, i just dont remember how and i hope u do, so u can tell me pls

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19109430/4204026) and you'll see how.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the `Scanner` as an object outside the main function and then you can use it in other functions.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class ScannerTest {

    private static Scanner scanner;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        start();
    }

    private static void start(){
        String input = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Input: " + input);
    }
}
```

**NOTE: The `scanner` object as well as the `start` function need to be static in order for you to access them inside the `main` function.**

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);

    int x = start(input);
    System.out.println("enter another number");
    int i = input.nextInt();

    System.out.println("a number:" + x);
    System.out.println("another number" + i);
}

public static int start(Scanner scan) {
    System.out.println("Please enter a number");
    int x = scan.nextInt();
    return x;
}
```

To use the Scanner in another method, send the Scanner in a parameter to the method, i.e. `start(Scanner scan)` and then `return x` to test and print the value in the main() method.

Comment: i think theres another way for the methods to recognize the scanner..
ill search my papers for this way and post it here..
but thank u very much man... i didnt know this way works too.. thanks bro

Comment: if you find this answer helpful please accept this as an answer you need to learn about method with parameter

Answer (score 0):

Solved, now it works great!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Exe1GenericSort {

    private static final Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    //...
```