# How do you pass variables to different methods

Tags: java

How do I pass the tom.name, id age and year variables from the main method into the 'tomdetails' method so that they are recognizable by that method?

```
class Student {
    int id;
    int age;
    int year;
    String name;
}

class Staff {
    int id;
    int age;
    String name;
    String postcode;
    String department;
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Database
        //Students
        Student tom = new Student();
        tom.name = "Tom";
        tom.id = 1;
        tom.age = 15;
        tom.year = 10;

       }

    private static void tom_details() {
        System.out.println(tom.name);
        System.out.println(tom.id);
        System.out.println(tom.age);
        System.out.println(tom.year);
    }
}
```

Comment: I recommend reading a tutorial on methods, e.g. [this one by oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pass variables between methods in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19109390/how-do-i-pass-variables-between-methods-in-java)

Comment: Object "tom" is local to main() method. This object is only accessible inside main() method. So you cannot access local member outside of scope, i.e. inside tom_details() method.

Comment: Two solution for this issue. 1) Pass "tom" object to the tom_details() method. 2) Declare "tom" object globally inside Main class with "static" keyword.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While you *could* pass the variables separately, it probably makes more sense to pass the reference to the whole `Student` object. For example:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Student tom = new Student();
    tom.name = "Tom";
    tom.id = 1;
    tom.age = 15;
    tom.year = 10;
    printDetails(tom);
}

private static void printDetails(Student student) {
    System.out.println(student.name);
    System.out.println(student.id);
    System.out.println(student.age);
    System.out.println(student.year);
}
```

The next steps I'd take after that would be:

- Give `Student` a constructor accepting the name, ID, age and year
- Make all the *fields* within `Student` private (and potentially final), instead exposing data via methods (e.g. `getName()`)
- Potentially add a `printDetails()` method within `Student` so that you could just call `tom.printDetails()` in your `main` method.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can pass just the object `tom`:
Change the method to

```
    private static void tom_details(Student tom) {
        System.out.println(tom.name);
        System.out.println(tom.id);
        System.out.println(tom.age);
        System.out.println(tom.year);
    }
```